# Integrate AngularJS with Google Tag Manager

Tags: angularjs, google-tag-manager

We get a code snippet from Google, but when I insert it into `index.html`, console would have error, and the whole app is not up.

After inserting Google Tag Manger code just before `</body>`, the whole `index.html` is like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title ng-bind="title"></title>
    <base href="/">
    <!- some scripts and link go here ->
    //scripts and link
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container main-container">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>

        <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5QMF5WC"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5QMF5WC');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
</body>
</html>
```

However, it does not work. Console always has below error:

```
client?cd17:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.bundle.js:167), <anonymous>:5:77)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.bundle.js:167), <anonymous>:98:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js:167)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js:47)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.bundle.js:20)
    at app.bundle.js:40
    at app.bundle.js:43
(anonymous) @ client?cd17:5
(anonymous) @ client?cd17:96
(anonymous) @ app.bundle.js:167
__webpack_require__ @ app.bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.bundle.js:47
__webpack_require__ @ app.bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.bundle.js:40
(anonymous) @ app.bundle.js:43
angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…20Ac%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fvendor%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:40
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at g (angular.min.js:39)
    at db (angular.min.js:43)
    at c (angular.min.js:21)
    at Ac (angular.min.js:21)
    at fe (angular.min.js:20)
    at angular.min.js:315
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:188)
```

If I remove the google tag manager code, then there is no any problem. So I am sure the error is caused by it.

UPDATE:
it turns out to be webpack problem.
https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/381

Answer (score 0):

The error actually shows there is an issue with the Module. Anyhow if you want to use google tag manager with angular i would suggest you to use [**`Angulartics`**](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics)

```
 var yourApp = angular.module('YourApp', ['angulartics', 'angulartics.google.analytics'])
```

Comment: I learned from http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/02/15/what-is-google-tag-manager/, google Analytics and google tag manager can work separately. Is it necessary to use Analytics?

Comment: @BenjaminLi yes thats possible. but when you do through this library it makes things easy for you